# Socket.io + Azure web sockets issue

Tags: node.js, azure, socket.io, azure-web-app-service

I am working on a multiplayer chess game with [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) and [socket.IO](http://socket.io/).

I have problem hosting it on Azure tho.. I tried many different approaches, a few mentioned:

Forcing the application to only use WebSockets by adding the code below:

```
io.configure(function() {
  io.set('transports', ['websocket']);
});
```

Added `<webSocket enabled="false"/>` in `web.config` file..

> **Note**: This disables the IIS WebSockets module, which includes its own implementation of WebSockets and conflicts with Node.js specific WebSocket modules such as Socket.IO. If this line is not present, or is set to true, this may be the reason that the WebSocket transport is not working for your application.

Matching origin protocol to ensure no SSL issues.

```
io.configure(function() {
  io.set('match origin protocol', true);
});
```

I now started from scratch, since I thought my server-side part was corrupt, and tried [Socket.io chat example](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat) instead.

- I followed the steps.
- Created a new web app on Azure.
- Published my files through FileZilla FTP.
- Enabled Web Sockets on Azure for my app (disabled by default).

[image]

---

STILL THE SAME ERROR! See picture below.

[image]

Anyone? I am unsure if it's a client-side or server-side issue. It seems like it's trying to XHR-poll instead of using web sockets..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this Azure Web Apps? Also, just to confirm, this works locally? I've got an example with a quick deploy button which uses Node and Socket.io. Something in there may help. https://github.com/christopheranderson/node-chat-sample

Comment: Azure Web app, yes. This works locally (both chat example and my chess game), forgot to add that. Thanks for the sample I will check it out.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious that you're doing wrong, which means it is probably a subtle thing. Try out my sample and see if you see similar issues. Since you're presumably uploading node_modules instead of using CI (native module support exists for node version 4.x.x and up), make sure you have matching node versions locally and on your web app.

Comment: No continous integration, just uploading manually. Before I uploaded I made sure I generated a fresh `packages.json` by doing `npm init` so it should match..

Comment: It's `node_modules` that needs refreshing. You can use `npm update` to refresh your packages. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update

Comment: Tried that too, no success. It seems like socket.io is trying to poll instead of using web sockets, if my server-side is saying "use sockets!" but my client-side is asking for polls. This is frustrating.

Comment: I just deployed the socket.io chat sample and it is using WebSockets. I cloned the repo, directly required socket.io in server.js and package.json, changed index.js to server.js, created a web app, turned on Always On and Socket.IO, git deploy, and it works! If you're still hitting walls, I can do a quick skype screen share to see if I can see your issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98839/discussion-between-urbz-and-chris-anderson-msft).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working, thank you [Chris Anderson-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3662111/chris-anderson-msft) for your help.

The weird thing that occurred for me when deploying with FTP was that my `node_modules` folder differed with version(s) specified in my `package.json`.

I solved this by connecting my web app on Azure to a local Git repository and deploying the app through git. This connects my packages recursively and matches correct versions.

I also needed to enforce my client-side socket-io to use web sockets by specifying transport method:

```
var socket = io({transports:['websocket']});
```

And this is what my server-side file ended up looking like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/default.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    io.set('transports', ['websocket']);
    console.log('new connection on socket.io');
    socket.on('move', function(msg) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('move', msg);
    });
});

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});
```

Comment: Something you can always do to try to root cause bad packages as your problem during FTP is to use the Debug Console on Kudu to delete your node_modules folder and run npm install from Kudu. Glad you fixed it, @urbz!

Comment: Thanks for the great tip @ChrisAnderson-MSFT